Getting hostname of each yb-tserver in YugabyteDB cluster using YSQL
How can I easily set host on startup of a yb-container, such that select * from yb_servers()  lists a hostname instead of an ip-address in the host column?
startup command for 6 docker nodes was:
docker run -d --network yb_net  \
  --hostname node4 --name node4 \
  -p7004:7000 -p9004:9000       \
  yugabytedb/yugabyte           \
  yugabyted start --background=false --join node1.yb_net

I can refer to the containers/nodes by nodename, but .. “inside” yugabuyte, these are known by their ip-addresses.. :
yugabyte=#
yugabyte=# select host, public_ip, zone, uuid from yb_servers() ;
    host    | public_ip  | zone  |              uuid             
------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------
 172.18.0.7 | 172.18.0.7 | rack1 | 4502b634a1864a2ca31a6cb3f8a5e95c
 172.18.0.6 | 172.18.0.6 | rack1 | aa2dadf52d8d4d53916545f76a83b17a
 172.18.0.2 | 172.18.0.2 | rack1 | 0eb6302873c7425480ee914761a88398
 172.18.0.4 | 172.18.0.4 | rack1 | 0e570ffd42d44b238615caaeb685872a
 172.18.0.3 | 172.18.0.3 | rack1 | 7011278b1e3f4e06bf66e938a0f64bc1
 172.18.0.5 | 172.18.0.5 | rack1 | ab4d2998c69b471795c56cd0fc79f3d0
(6 rows)
yugabyte=#

I would like to do select host from yb_servers(), and see the hostname instead of an IP ..

The yugabyted start command has a flag for that:
 --advertise_address=node2 

Using that flag, the names in the yb_servers() function, and in stdout from yugatool and yb-admin, come out as hostnames.

PostgreSQL & YugabyteDB doesn't provide a builtin function returning the server's hostname.
There is an extension that you can use: https://pgxn.org/dist/hostname/. This should give you the hostname of the server you’ve connected to. So you should do the query for each server, but you can easily cache it and run it only once.
If you are a superuser, you can connect to each yb-tserver directly and do:
select pg_read_file('/etc/hostname') as hostname;

